# SQL Subquery Not Returning What I Expect

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this problem to solve: **If two students A and B are friends, and A likes B but not vice-versa, remove the Likes entry**.

For background, the Friend table has two columns, STU1 and STU2. If they are friends, then there will be an entry showing STU1, STU2 AND STU2, STU1.

In the Likes table, if Student A likes Student B, there will be an entry for STU1, STU2, but if Student B does not like Student A, there will NOT be an entry for STU2, STU1.

So, here is what I have tried. The problem is that it still leaves two rows in the Likes table that should be out of there. Any ideas on how to solve this on?

```
delete from Likes
where exists 
    (select F.STU1, F.STU2 from Friend F
        where exists  
        (select L.STU1, L.STU2 from Likes L, Friend F where
            F.STU1 = L.STU1 and F.STU2 = L.STU2)
        )
    and not exists
        (select L.STU1, L.STU2 from Likes L, Friend F where
            F.STU1 = L.STU2 and F.STU2 = L.STU1)
```

Comment: Which RBDMS?  I'm assuming Sql Server because of the tags used for your other question...

Answer (score 0):

edit:

```
with onewayfriends as (
select f.* from friend f
left outer join likes l1 on l1.stu1=f.stu1 and l1.stu2=f.stu2
left outer join likes l2 on l2.stu1=f.stu2 and l2.stu2=f.stu1
where l1.stu1 is null or l2.stu1 is null)

delete l from likes l, onewayfriends f
where l.stu1 in (f.stu1, f.stu2) and l.stu2 in (f.stu1, f.stu2)
```

edit 2, since it's sqllite rewrite the cte as a nested query and the delete with join as a 'where row id in..'

```
delete from likes where rowid in (select l.rowid from
(
  select f.* from friend f
  left outer join likes l1 on l1.stu1=f.stu1 and l1.stu2=f.stu2
  left outer join likes l2 on l2.stu1=f.stu2 and l2.stu2=f.stu1
  where l1.stu1 is null or l2.stu1 is null
) f, likes l
where l.stu1 in (f.stu1, f.stu2) and l.stu2 in (f.stu1, f.stu2))
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/87ab8/12/0)

Comment: This is using SQLite, and it crashed on the "with" clause.

Comment: @JoefromPhilly didn't realize it was sqllite, try the edit2 version

Comment: So, I get a syntax error when I try to run this. I then modified it by replacing "delete l" with: "delete from Likes
where exists (select * ..... [your query])   and I get the empty set as a result. I played with the schema to add other rows, and the right set gets returned, but something is going wrong in the delete portion.

Answer (score 0):

You said that the Friend table has both pairs.  So we need to delete pairs from the Likes table where that pair is in the Friend table, but the anti-pair does not exist in the Likes table.

```
DELETE
FROM Likes
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Friend f WHERE Likes.STU1 = f.STU1 AND Likes.STU2 = f.STU2)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Likes ml WHERE Likes.STU1 = ml.STU2 AND Likes.STU2 = ml.STU1)
```

Comment: Mixing plural/singular table names causes much frustration.

Comment: I will try this one that you just put in.

Comment: However, what is meant by "SELECT 1 FROM"? I don't get the "l".

Comment: Here is the error that is returned:  Query failed to execute: near "l": syntax error

Comment: Basically, "delete l" is crashing.

Comment: I changed it around, and this works: DELETE
FROM Likes
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Friend f WHERE Likes.STU1 = f.STU1 AND Likes.STU2 = f.STU2)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Likes ml WHERE Likes.STU1 = ml.STU2 AND Likes.STU2 = ml.STU1)

Comment: Yes. Aliasing in delete statements is a bit of a syntax trouble spot in various sql dialects... TSql went as far as to allow two FROM clauses.

Comment: @DavidB to be fair the first from clause isn't really a from clause and should be omitted anyways `delete b from table1 a, table2 b ..`